# Uploading image in paperclip lags my server for 3 minutes and then gives me error

Tags: image, upload, paperclip

This is my controller

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]
  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /pins
  # GET /pins.json
  def index
    @pins = Pin.all
  end

  # GET /pins/1
  # GET /pins/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /pins/new
  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.new
  end

  # GET /pins/1/edit
  def edit
    @pin = current_user.pins.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /pins
  # POST /pins.json
  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.new(pin_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @pin.save
        format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @pin }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /pins/1
  # PATCH/PUT /pins/1.json
  def update
    @pin = current_user.pins.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @pin.update(pin_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @pin }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /pins/1
  # DELETE /pins/1.json
  def destroy
    @pin = current_user.pins.find(params[:id])
    @pin.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to pins_url, notice: 'Pin was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image)
    end
end
```

This is my model

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :description, :image
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "320x240>"}

    validates :description, presence: true
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates_attachment :image, presence: true,
                        content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/gif", "image/png"] },
                        size: { in: 0..5.megabytes }

    belongs_to :user

end
```

When I try to upload an image, my server lags for 3 minutes, console goes crazy and after those 3 minutes I get this error message - "has contents that are not what they are reported to be".

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the model to this

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :description, :image
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "320x240>"}

    validates :description, presence: true
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates_attachment :image, presence: true,
                        # content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/gif", "image/png"] },
                        size: { in: 0..5.megabytes }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage/

    belongs_to :user

end
```